# Can't bind click event to appended element

Tags: jquery, click, append, bind

I have been newbie, and I have following problem:

One of the goals is to click "space" in the first user input field, and "Tag" should appear under.
 I don't know how to click just one of "Tags" ?
 When I click one tag, everything is removed. I need to remove just the clicked Tag.
Thank you in advance.

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" name="prvi" id="prvi" value="Tag"></input>

    <button type="button" id="ponisti" name="ponistavanje">Poništi</button>
    <div class="prikazati"><br></div>
    <hr>
    <input type="number" name="broj1" placeholder="min"></input>
    <input type="number" name="broj2" placeholder="max"></input>
    <button type="button" name="generisi">Generiši</button>
    <script>
    var brojac = 1;
    $('#prvi').on('input', function(e) {
    if (e.target.value === ' ') {
    $('.prikazati').append('Tag' + brojac);
    $('#prvi').val('');
    brojac += 1;
    }
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.prikazati', function() {
       $(this).remove();
    });

    $('#ponisti').click(function() {
    $('.prikazati').html('<br>');
    brojac = 1;
    });

    </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Interesting, perhaps it's necessary to append each tag in a separate div so that they can be targeted separately?

Comment: Using what @IronMan said, here's a quick fix to do what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/3w2s8gp7/